# Check if Tab key is held down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is pressed and held down and released so that I can perform some other actions with other key combinations.

```
var shifted = false;
var tabbed  = false;
 
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function(e) {        
  shifted = e.shiftKey;
  tabbed  = e.keyCode === 9;
    
  console.log(tabbed);
});
```

The above code is working fine for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, but it's not working for the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. When the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is pressed and held the `tabbed` variable should be `true` and when released it should be `false`.

Comment: User navigating via keyboard rely heavily on [tab], assigning it any other functionality of your own is a _very_ bad idea IMHO.

Comment: Note that the [tab] key is *not* a modifier key like shift/alt/control/winkey.   It's a normal key like any other - this would be like asking the user to hold down A and press another key.

Comment: Adding to what @CBroe said, if you are using tab key for a purpose other than managing focus then it is not a good idea. Since you are using shift here too I have a feeling this has something to do with accessibility. Please confirm.

Comment: I would guess that the issue with Tab working in this way is because it moves the focus around the DOM, unlike Shift or most other keys, and interrupts the key event which was fired. I don't think there's much you can do to avoid this issue - not without completely violating most accessibility rules anyway. Can you please describe what goal you're trying to reach as this solution is very far from ideal and there is most likely a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question (rather than question if the question should be a question):

[This MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#keyboardevent_sequence) describes how keyboard events work.

- one keydown, with repeat = false
- multiple keydown, with repeat = true
- one keyup

So you can check for when the tab is started to be held down with `keydown && !repeat` and when it's stopped being held down with `keyup`

Note you must also cancel the event so that it doesn't do the correct/expected behaviour of tabbing to the next tabbed-indexed input (emphasis on what *tab* actually should be doing...)

It's also cleaner to keep the events separate, giving:

```js
var tabdown  = false;

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
      tabdown = true;
      return false;
    }
    
    if (tabdown && e.keyCode >= 49 && e.keyCode <= 51) 
    {
      $("#in" + (e.keyCode-48)).focus();
      return false;
    }
});
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) tabdown = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<em>hold tab and 1, 2 or 3 to change inputs</em><br/>
<input type='text' id='in1'>
<input type='text' id='in2'>
<input type='text' id='in3'>
```

But you'll note that an instruction is needed on the page as it's not a normal method - and also disables the normal method to easily/quickly switch between inputs in order.

**This is not a recommended course of action.**

But included here for completeness.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following to identify is tabbed

```
tabbed  = (e.keyCode === 9 && e.type === 'keydown')?true:false;
```